# condition for predicting probability of heart disease in machine learning

Tags: python, html

this is the HTML code

```
<!-- Result -->
    <div class="results">
        {% if prediction == 1%}
        <h1 style="color: red;">Prediction: <span class='danger'>Oops! You have Chances of Heart Disease.</span></h1>
        {% elif prediction == 0%}
        <h1 style="color: green;">Prediction: <span class='safe'>Great! You don't have chances of Heart Disease.</span></h1>`enter code here`
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

The output always shows chances of heart disease whatever the input

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

{% elif prediction == 0%}

should be

{% elseif prediction == 0%}